# CSS3 :not() selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the following situation, how can I use `:not()` to exclude `div.note em`  from being bold?

```css
div#content em {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* I want to remove the following 
   in favor of the :not selector being applied to the above */
div#content div.note em {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

PS:  This is a stripped-down example, I actually have a number of styles in `div#content em` that I want to apply to everything except `div.note em`. That's why I don't want to overwrite them all manually lateron...

Comment: Due to the nature of descendant combinators, you cannot do this reliably with `:not()` alone. You'll have to create some sort of complex selector that depends on your HTML structure, and the effort to do that is not worth just using your `div#content div.note em` overriding rule instead.

Comment: (I don't know if such a selector is even possible. It really depends on your markup.)

Comment: Well, the markup is pretty much like the CSS suggests... Imagine `div#content` to be like `article` and then `div.note` to be one highlighted info-box within that article, besides all the other things like `p`s, `blockquote`s, images and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the exact hierarchy between `#content` and `.note`, you can use child selectors to make the negation specific enough to work. If `.note` is a child of `#content`, you use:

```css
#content > :not(.note) em, #content > em {}
```

If there are two `<div>`s between `#content` and `.note`, do something like:

```css
#content > div > div > :not(.note) em, #content > em {}
```

You're probably better off using what you have, though, and just overriding em elements that are descendants of .note.

Comment: Also, you really don't need to qualify your id and class selectors with  tags unless adding the tag changes the selector (i.e., you have #content or .note elements that are not divs).